# Data from 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, angular

So i have two arrays:
1:

```
"movies":
```

{

```
  "id": "123bb",

  "category": "3345",

  "content": "Sinister"

}
```

Second:

```
"categories":
```

{

```
  "id": "3345",

  "code": "Movie",

  "name": "Horror"

},
```

I also have random movie:
TS:

```
    loadData() {

    this.PagesService.loadData().subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)

      this.movies = response

      this.movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.movies.length)];

      this.randomValue = this.movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.movies.length)];

      return this.randomValue

    })

    console.log(this.randomValue)

  };
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{ this.randomValue.content }}</p>
```

So if I have something like this:

```
<p>{{ this.randomValue.category }}</p>
```

There is "3345" as category but I would like to have "name" from this second array but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: Where do you load categories?

Comment: You need to `find` the object in the `categories` array whose `id` matches the `category` of the random object you selected from `movies`.

Comment: Thats actually only thing I know... I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

**My recommendation:**

- store the data as observable
- map the data in observable pipe (maybe use combineLatest to combine movies and categories data)
- use the async pipe in template
- use an own structural directive to pick the datas random element

Here is how it could look like...

**The directive**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface RandomContext<T> {
  appRandom: T[];
  $implicit?: T;
}

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[appRandom]',
})
export class RandomDirective<T> {
  private context: RandomContext<T> = {
    appRandom: [],
    $implicit: undefined,
  };

  @Input()
  set appRandom(elements: T[]) {
    this.context.appRandom = elements;
    this.pickNewElement();
  }

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
  }

  private pickNewElement(): void {
    this.context.$implicit =
      this.context.appRandom[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.context.appRandom.length)
      ];
  }
}
```

**And your template:**

```
<p *appRandom="movies$ | async; let randomMovie">
  {{ randomMovie.category }}
</p>
```

**And your component:**

```
movies$: Observable<ExtendedMovie[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.movies$ = combineLatest([
    this.PagesService.loadData(),
    this.CategoriesService.loadCategories(),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([movies, categories]) => {
      return /*map movies array to extend it with your required data from categories array*/;
    }),
  );
}
```